# Car Rental with DataBase

Tags: java

it would be very interesting to hear suggestions about my the newest project - Car Rental that interact with Data Base. It doesn't have GUI, because I haven't learned it before. That's because you will find a lot of sys.out.print lines.
It contains a lot of classes, I will put down here the most important. 
At the bottom I will put link to the project on my github.
You can ask why by creating new client random number is shown. That's because I didn't know how to pair User Object and Client Object, so my App doesn't have possibility to create accounts for  user nor worker. Client number is required for example in renting a car. User must input this number. If he want to populate all the rented cars, he must input the same client number that he inputted during renting. That is how every client is unique - it has his own number.

**DataBase** class. Contain methods that are responsible for adding/deleting/updating... data in my database. Methods are long, because I used prepared statements. I heard, it's good practice. In methods like `rentACar`, `makeCarUnavailable`, `makeCarAvailable` I added functionality which takes responsible for throwing a message if car doesn't exist.

```
public class DataBase {
private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
private ResultSet result;

public DataBase() throws SQLException {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rentalcar?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=" + TimeZone.getDefault().getID(), "root", "...");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
}

public void insertNewCustomer(Client client) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into client" + "(namee, surname, street,houseNumber,city,peselNumber,rentDate, clientNumber)" + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    preparedStatement.setString(1, client.getName());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, client.getSurname());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, client.getStreet());
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, client.getHouseNumber());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, client.getCity());
    preparedStatement.setLong(6, client.getPeselNumber());
    preparedStatement.setString(7, client.getRentDate());
    preparedStatement.setInt(8, client.getClientNumber());

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}

public void insertNewCar(Car car) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into car" + "(brand, productionYear, engineCapacity,dayPrice,available)" + "values(?,?,?,?,?)");

    preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getBrand());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, car.getProductionYear());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, car.getEngineCapacity());
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, car.getDayPrice());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, car.getAvailable());

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}

public void rentACar(RentingACar rentingACar) throws SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isAvailable = true;
    {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM car WHERE available='1' AND brand=?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, rentingACar.getBrand());
        result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
    while (result.next()) {
        count = result.getInt(1);
    }
    if (count < 1)
        isAvailable = false;

    if (isAvailable) {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into rentcar" + "(brand,namee,surname,rentDate,clientNumber)" + "values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, rentingACar.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, rentingACar.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, rentingACar.getSurname());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, rentingACar.getRentDate());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, rentingACar.getClientNumber());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update car " + " set available='0'" + " where brand= ? ");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, rentingACar.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Car was rented!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no " + rentingACar.getBrand() + " in our car or all types of this car are rented!");
    }
}

public void returnACar(Car car) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE from rentcar WHERE brand=? AND clientNumber=?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getBrand());
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, car.getClientNumber());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update car " + " set available='1'" + " where brand=?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getBrand());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}

public void makeCarUnavailable(Car car) throws SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isAvailable = true;
    {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM car WHERE brand=? AND productionYear=? ");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, car.getProductionYear());
        result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
    while (result.next()) {
        count = result.getInt(1);
    }
    if (count < 1)
        isAvailable = false;

    if (isAvailable) {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update car " + " set available='0'" + " where brand=? AND productionYear=?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, car.getProductionYear());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(car.getBrand() + " was made unavailable");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No " + car.getBrand() + " in system!");
    }
}

public void makeCarAvailable(Car car) throws SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isAvailable = true;
    {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM car WHERE brand=? AND productionYear=? ");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, car.getProductionYear());
        result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
    while (result.next()) {
        count = result.getInt(1);
    }
    if (count < 1)
        isAvailable = false;

    if (isAvailable) {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update car " + " set available='1'" + " where brand=? AND productionYear=?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, car.getProductionYear());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(car.getBrand() + " was made unavailable");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No " + car.getBrand() + " in system!");
    }
}

public void populateTableViewCars(Car car) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM car WHERE dayPrice > ?");
    preparedStatement.setDouble(1, car.getDayPrice());
    result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while (result.next()) {

        String brand = result.getString("brand");
        String productionYear = result.getString("productionYear");
        String engineCapacity = result.getString("engineCapacity");
        String dayPrice = result.getString("dayPrice");
        String available = result.getString("available");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.printf("Brand:" + brand + "\nEngine Capacity:" + engineCapacity + "\nDayPrice:" + dayPrice + "\nProduction Year:" + productionYear + "\navailable:" + available + "\n");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }
}


public void populateTableRent(Client client) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM rentcar WHERE clientNumber=?");
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, client.getClientNumber());
    result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while (result.next()) {

        String brand = result.getString("brand");
        String name = result.getString("namee");
        String surname = result.getString("surname");
        String rentDate = result.getString("rentDate");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.printf("Brand:" + brand + "\nName:" + name + "\nSurname:" + surname + "\nDate of rental:" + rentDate + "\n");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }
}

public void populateTableViewClients() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM `client`";
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (result.next()) {

        String namee = result.getString("namee");
        String surname = result.getString("surname");
        String street = result.getString("street");
        int houseNumber = result.getInt("houseNumber");
        long peselNumber = result.getLong("peselNumber");
        String rentDate = result.getString("rentDate");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.printf("Name:" + namee + "\nSurname:" + surname + "\nStreet:" + street + "\nNumber of house:" + houseNumber + "\nPesel number:" + peselNumber + "\nDate of rental:" + rentDate + "\n");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }
}
}
```

I've package named DataGetter that contains 2 classes - **WorkerDataGetter** and **ClientDataGetter**. 
They contain methods that are responsible for getting data and creating objects. For example in WorkerDataGetter we can find `createCar` method that is collecting data from user and creating object of new car that will be passed to databases' methods.

**WorkerDataGetter**

```
public class WorkerDataGetter {
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public Car createCar() {
    Car car = new Car();

    System.out.print("Brand: ");
    car.setBrand(input.next());
    System.out.print("Day price: ");
    car.setDayPrice(input.nextInt());
    System.out.print("Engine Capcity: ");
    car.setEngineCapacity(input.next());
    System.out.print("Production year: ");
    car.setProductionYear(input.next());
    System.out.print("available: ");
    car.setAvailable(input.next());

    return car;
}

public Car makeCarUnavailable() {
    Car car = new Car();

    System.out.print("Brand: ");
    car.setBrand(input.next());
    System.out.print("production year: ");
    car.setProductionYear(input.next());

    return car;
}

public Car makeCarAavailable() {
    Car car = new Car();

    System.out.print("Brand: ");
    car.setBrand(input.next());
    System.out.print("Production year : ");
    car.setProductionYear(input.next());

    return car;
}
}
```

**ClientDataGetter**

```
public class ClientDataGetter {
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private Random rand = new Random();

public Client createClient() {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.setClientNumber(rand.nextInt(999));

    System.out.print("name: ");
    client.setName(input.next());
    System.out.print("surname: ");
    client.setSurname(input.next());
    System.out.print("city: ");
    client.setCity(input.next());
    System.out.print("house number: ");
    client.setHouseNumber(input.nextInt());
    System.out.print("street: ");
    client.setStreet(input.next());
    System.out.print("pesel number: ");
    client.setPeselNumber(input.nextLong());
    System.out.print("rent date: ");
    client.setRentDate(input.next());
    System.out.println("Your client number is: " + client.getClientNumber());

    return client;
}

public RentingACar rentACar() {
    RentingACar rentingACar = new RentingACar();

    System.out.print("Brand: ");
    rentingACar.setBrand(input.next());
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    rentingACar.setName(input.next());
    System.out.print("Surname: ");
    rentingACar.setSurname(input.next());
    System.out.print("Rent Date: ");
    rentingACar.setRentDate(input.next());
    System.out.print("Client number: ");
    rentingACar.setClientNumber(input.nextInt());

    return rentingACar;
}

public Car populateTableViewCars() {
    Car car = new Car();

    System.out.println("Input minimum price per day. If you want to display all cars - input 0.\nMinimum price: ");
    car.setDayPrice(input.nextInt());

    return car;
}

public Client populateTableRent() {
    Client client = new Client();

    System.out.println("Input your client number: ");
    client.setClientNumber(input.nextInt());

    return client;
}

public Car returnACar() {
    Car car = new Car();

    System.out.println("Input brand of car that you want to return: ");
    car.setBrand(input.next());
    System.out.println("Input your client number, otherwise car won't be removed from our DataBase!");
    car.setClientNumber(input.nextInt());

    return car;
}
}
```

**CarRentalOptions** class - contains all the methods that we can find in the App.

```
public class CarRentalOptions {
private DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();

CarRentalOptions() throws SQLException {
}

void createNewCustomer(Client client) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.insertNewCustomer(client);

    System.out.println("Client added successfully!");
}

void createNewCar(Car car) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.insertNewCar(car);

    System.out.println("Car added successfully!");
}

void makeCarUnavailable(Car car) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.makeCarUnavailable(car);
}

void makeCarAvailable(Car car) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.makeCarAvailable(car);
}

void rentACar(RentingACar rentingACar) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.rentACar(rentingACar);
}

void populateTableViewCars(Car car) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.populateTableViewCars(car);
}

void populateTableRent(Client client) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.populateTableRent(client);
}

void populateTableViewClients() throws SQLException {
    dataBase.populateTableViewClients();
}

void returnACar(Car car) throws SQLException {
    dataBase.returnACar(car);
}
}
```

**CarRentalEngine** - the brain of the App

```
public class CarRentalEngine {
private int option;
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private CarRentalOptions carRentalOptions = new CarRentalOptions();
private ClientDataGetter clientDataGetter = new ClientDataGetter();
private WorkerDataGetter workerDataGetter = new WorkerDataGetter();

CarRentalEngine() throws SQLException {
}

void startCarRental() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("Who are you?\n1. Customer\n2. Worker");
    try {
        switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                executeClientCase();
                break;
            case 2:
                executeWorkerCase();
                break;
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Your input is wrong!");
    }
}


private void executeOptionsForClient(int option) throws SQLException {
    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            carRentalOptions.rentACar(clientDataGetter.rentACar());
            break;
        case 2:
            carRentalOptions.returnACar(clientDataGetter.returnACar());
            break;
        case 3:
            carRentalOptions.populateTableRent(clientDataGetter.populateTableRent());
            break;
        case 4:
            carRentalOptions.populateTableViewCars(clientDataGetter.populateTableViewCars());
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }
}


private void executeOptionsForWorker(int option) throws SQLException {
    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            carRentalOptions.populateTableViewClients();
            break;
        case 2:
            carRentalOptions.populateTableViewCars(clientDataGetter.populateTableViewCars());
            break;
        case 3:
            carRentalOptions.makeCarAvailable(workerDataGetter.makeCarAavailable());
            break;
        case 4:
            carRentalOptions.makeCarUnavailable(workerDataGetter.makeCarUnavailable());
            break;
        case 5:
            carRentalOptions.createNewCar(workerDataGetter.createCar());
        case 6:
            break;
    }
}


private void executeClientCase() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("1. Have you inputted your data before?\nN/Y: ");
    if (input.next().toUpperCase().equals("N")) {
        carRentalOptions.createNewCustomer(clientDataGetter.createClient());
        System.out.println("Now you have your unique number clinet, use it where it is required!");
    } else {
        do {
            System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
            System.out.println("1. Rent a car\n2. Return a car\n3. Populate rented cars\n4. Populate cars\n5. Quit");
            option = input.nextInt();
            executeOptionsForClient(option);
        }
        while (option != 5);
    }
}

private void executeWorkerCase() throws SQLException {
    do {
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("1. Populate clients\n2. Populate cars\n3. Make car available\n4. Make car unavailable\n5. Insert new car\n6. Quit");
        option = input.nextInt();
        executeOptionsForWorker(option);
    }
    while (option != 6);
}
}
```

I've got also classes like Car, Client, RentingACar - they contains getters and setters. You can find it on my github CarRental/Model. Here is the link: https://github.com/must1/RentalCar .

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DataBase**

In `DataBase` class I'd use method scoped variables, rather than class properties. In general, it's better to have method scoped variables since you can keep control about their state. This way:

```
public void rentACar(RentingACar rentingACar) throws SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isAvailable = true;
    {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM car WHERE available='1' AND brand=?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, rentingACar.getBrand());
        ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
    while (result.next()) {
        count = result.getInt(1);
    }
    if (count < 1)
        isAvailable = false;

    if (isAvailable) {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into rentcar" + "(brand,namee,surname,rentDate,clientNumber)" + "values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, rentingACar.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, rentingACar.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, rentingACar.getSurname());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, rentingACar.getRentDate());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, rentingACar.getClientNumber());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update car " + " set available='0'" + " where brand= ? ");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, rentingACar.getBrand());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Car was rented!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no " + rentingACar.getBrand() + " in our car or all types of this car are rented!");
    }
}
```

Also you can follow up two different strategies here from the DB point of view. Use a single connection and keep it opened (it's quite expensive to open a DB connection) or open a connection for each transaction you want to perform. [There's a variety of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962852/should-a-database-connection-stay-open-all-the-time-or-only-be-opened-when-neede) about this matter, generally for production environments the second strategy goes well, but with a connection pool under the covers.

Anyway, considering you want to use a single connection, you need to close your `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` after having used them. Starting from Java 7, that [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15728512/1199132) in the `try` syntax:

```
try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
    try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("some query")) {
        // Do stuff with the result set.
    }
    try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("some query")) {
        // Do more stuff with the second result set.
    }
}
```

Also, I personally prefer to wrap up the `SqlException`s in some customized exceptions. This way you make an abstraction over the DB layer, but you'll be able to know the details upwards. Kind of this:

```
public class DBException extends RuntimeException{
  //Here write a constructor that can be called with any other exception
  public DBException(Throwable ex){
    super(ex);
  }
}
```

Being it a runtime exception [you don't need to repeatingly specify it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190177/1199132) with the `throws` keyword, but you're able to catch it upwards if desired. You can use it this way:

```
public void methodThatDoesDBStuff(){
  try{
   //DB stuff
  } catch(SQLException ex /*Add any other exception types here if you want*/){
    throw new DBException(ex);
  }
}
```

Next point is about DB transactions. Imagine that in your `rentACar` method, you get the renting info properly inserted in DB, but the query for updating the car fails. You would leave the DB in an inconsistent state. That's where [DB transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) come to rescue. JDBC as you're using it performs a transaction per action, but you can configure it to [disable the autocommit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940814/1199132) and perform the commit when everything has gone right.

**Data Getters**

I see the goal of these classes is to fill the data classes with user input. Howewever, as they're created in the main engine and the engine itself declares a `Scanner` object to read from the user input, I would use this input and pass it as a parameter to the methods:

```
carRentalOptions.rentACar(clientDataGetter.rentACar(input));
```

And in ClientDataGetter, having removed its `Scanner`:

```
public RentingACar rentACar(Scanner input) {
    RentingACar rentingACar = new RentingACar();

    System.out.print("Brand: ");
    rentingACar.setBrand(input.next());
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    rentingACar.setName(input.next());
    System.out.print("Surname: ");
    rentingACar.setSurname(input.next());
    System.out.print("Rent Date: ");
    rentingACar.setRentDate(input.next());
    System.out.print("Client number: ");
    rentingACar.setClientNumber(input.nextInt());

    return rentingACar;
}
```